# Api Platform: how to test file upload with ApiTestCase

Tags: php, symfony, upload, functional-testing, api-platform.com

I have an endpoint, that allows file upload, everything works fine.
Next thing is to cover the endpoint with proper functional test.
And here's the problem - I can't pass the `file` to the client making the request.

My test class extends `\ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\Test\ApiTestCase`.

`static::createClient()` method creates an instance of `ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\Test\Client` and these `Client` does not support file uploads.

Beacuse of implementing the `Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface` which defines `public function request(string $method, string $url, array $options = []): ResponseInterface;` there's no place for passing `files` argument.

The allowed `options` in `Client` does not support `files` array.

Internaly it looks like this:

`ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\Test\Client::request` passes to the internal `kernelBrowser` an empty array in place of `files` params (2nd array): `$this->kernelBrowser->request($method, $resolvedUrl, [], [], $server, $options['body'] ?? null)`

How do you test endpoints with file upload by extending `Base class for functional API tests` which is `ApiTestCase`?

Here's some code, to help you visualize the problem:

ApiResource definition in entity:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "file_upload"={
 *             "method"="post",
 *             "controller"=FileUpload::class,
 *             "path"="/api/file-upload-endpoint",
 *             "deserialize"=false,
 *             "openapi_context"={
 *                 "requestBody"={
 *                     "content"={
 *                         "multipart/form-data"={
 *                             "schema"={
 *                                 "type"="object",
 *                                 "properties"={
 *                                     "file"={
 *                                         "type"="string",
 *                                         "format"="binary"
 *                                     }
 *                                 }
 *                             }
 *                         }
 *                     }
 *                 }
 *             }
 *         },
 *     },
 * )
 */
```

Test class (don't mind the instance of `UploadedFile`, it's just there, to show you, that it cannot be passed anywhere):

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Tests\Api;

use \ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\Test\ApiTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

final class FileUploadTest extends ApiTestCase
{
    public function testFileUploadSuccessfully():void
    {
        $file = new UploadedFile(
            TESTS_PROJECT_DIR.'/tests/files/Small_sample_of_jet.jpg',
            'Small_sample_of_jet.jpg',
            'image/jpeg',
        );

        static::createClient()->request(
            'POST',
            '/api/file-upload-endpoint',
            [
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
                ],
            ],
        );

        self::assertResponseIsSuccessful();
        self::assertResponseHeaderSame('content-type', 'application/ld+json; charset=utf-8');
    }
}
```

And here is what i'm looking for:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Tests\Api;

use \ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\Test\ApiTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

final class FileUploadTest extends ApiTestCase
{
    public function testFileUploadSuccessfully():void
    {
        $file = new UploadedFile(
            TESTS_PROJECT_DIR.'/tests/files/Small_sample_of_jet.jpg',
            'Small_sample_of_jet.jpg',
            'image/jpeg',
        );

        static::createClient()->request(
            'POST',
            '/api/file-upload-endpoint',
            [
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
                ],
            ],
            [
                'file'=>$file
            ]
        );

        self::assertResponseIsSuccessful();
        self::assertResponseHeaderSame('content-type', 'application/ld+json; charset=utf-8');
    }
}
```

When modyfing the `vendor` itself and passing the `files` to the `Client::request` and then to the `kernelBrowser` in place of 2nd empty array, everything works fine (I'm aware of breaking the contract, that's not the issue here ;)).

I'm thinking if there's missing feature of uploading files in `ApiTestCase` or I just can't find the solution.

Pls halp!

Api Platform version: 2.5.6

PS: I know i can use different client - `test.client`

```
$client = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('test.client');
```

which is an instance of `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\KernelBrowser`, the same that is used internally by the Api Platform's `Client` and that **supports** `files` array, but that's not the point of my question. I'd like to know how to do file upload with `ApiTestCase`.

Comment: Is [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#uploading-data) usefull ? ctrl + f _To submit a form with file uploads__.

Comment: Unfortunately not. `kernelBrowser->request` which is used by `Client::request` extends `Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\AbstractBrowser` and `body` param is required to be `string` or `null`. It's not accepting `object`, `resource` and other stuff, that are allowed in `HttpClient`.

Comment: The `content` param, to be specific. The `body` param from `Client::request` is internally passed do `KernelBrowser` as a `content` param.

Comment: @MarekSkopowski did you ever manage to find a way to do this?

Comment: @AnonymousAngelo yup, I found workaround, but since I noticed that there's a PR to pass the files via the `extra` param i wasn't investigating further.

Comment: @AnonymousAngelo and believe me or not, but yesterday I fought about closing this issue ;)

Comment: Your post here definitely helped point me in the right direction. So thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the current latest release of [`api-platform/core`](https://github.com/api-platform/core/releases/tag/v2.5.8) (2.5.8) we are able to pass more parameters to `kernelBrowser->request` via the `extra` key. This also now includes files!

Here is a very basic example of testing an image upload (implemented based on the [official API Platform documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/file-upload/)):

```php
$file = new UploadedFile(
    'path/to/images/my_image.png',
    'my_image.png',
    'image/png',
);

$response = static::createClient()->request('POST', '/upload_image',
    [
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'],
        'extra' => [
            'files' => [
                'file' => $file,
            ],
        ],
    ],
);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for an update. I was going to make a PR to fix this issue, but I notcied that someone already did it.

Comment: No worries! If you think my answer is helpful, would you mind marking it as the accepted answer? :)

Comment: Yes, your answer is exactly what people will be looking for. Unfortunately my reputation (11 at the moment) do not allow me to vote publicly - "do not change the publicly displayed post score" ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ahh I understand :) So you can't even click on the green check mark?

Comment: LOL, I must be blind. Answer accepted :+1

Comment: it will be more clear https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/3299

Answer (score 1):

**Update for 2023:**

I want to add that you can not only attach files to your simulated `multipart` request, but also "$_POST" parameters (which will be accessible throguh $request->request) using the `request` method like this:

```
$file = new UploadedFile(
    'path/to/images/my_image.png',
    'my_image.png',
    'image/png',
);

$response = static::createClient()->request('POST', '/upload_image',
    [
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'],
        'extra' => [
            'files' => [
                'file' => $file,
            ],
            'parameters' => [
                'foo' => 'bar', // <- This
            ],
        ],
    ],
);
```

This is not really documented in the API Platform Testing Docs, so I thought I should leave it here.